# How To Sync data from MySQL to Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization, linked-server

i have MySQL table and i want to sync its data to same table but in SQL server any idea?
i have tried linked server but it works only from SQL server to insert into MySQL and i couldn't create trigger on linked server table is there anyway to access this MySQL linked server table inside my asp.net core 3.1 project or even create trigger on linked server table that update SQL server table?

Comment: Do you mean you want the data to be synchronised in real time, with consistency? That is to say, you don't want your transaction to complete unless the data exists in both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: @allmhuran the scenario is as following i have  MySql database Table and i want to keep another sql server table updated with any changes to the MySQL table i have created MySQL linked server , i can insert update delete from mysql using openquery but i couldn't  create trigger o n mysql linked server to update sql server table

Comment: Yes, but do you care how quickly the SQL Server table gets updated? Are you trying to ensure consistency across both tables, like a distributed transaction? Or is it OK if the SQL Server table gets updated by an independent process?

Comment: @allmhuran yes i want know if is it possible and then i will talk about consistency

Comment: The approaches you can take depend entirely upon whether you want to be sure that the data exists in both places. Since you're talking about using a trigger to do it, it sounds like you do want to make sure that the data is committed to both MySQL and SQL Server "at the same time", ie, within one transaction. Otherwise you could use approaches like ETL, change data capture, event generation, and so on. But it's still not clear if that really is your requirement.

Comment: @allmhuran my source is mysql table and i want to keep sql server table updated with any change in mysql(insert update delete)  alll matter to me is that sql server table have latest updated version of mysql table

Comment: If you don't care how quickly the tables get synched, I wouldn't suggest looking for a solution that tries to do a distributed transaction. Just use some kind of ETL process running on a schedule.

Comment: @allmhuran thanks for your help but i am back-end developer and i am new to this field can u simplify it for me plz :) better to provide topic or video handel my case

Comment: There are lots of different ways to run an Extract/Transform/Load process. If you are using SQL Server, you might want to look into SSIS. You read the data out of the source table, then move it over the network and write it to the destination. You can write to a staging table, and then use the TSQL merge statement to do the write to the "real" table. I can't really explain all of the ways of doing ETL here on SO :)

Comment: @allmhuran u mean that i have to store data from mysql linked server table in intermediate table in sql ? but i dont know  to do so .but i want to do it automatically using trigger or whatever you suggest

Comment: I think you need more information than can realistically be provided on stackoverflow. If you are able, I suggest engaging a colleague with experience in SQL and ETL processes.

Comment: i didn't get it so far can u provide tutorial or video plz? as matter of fact i think i have understand half of your answer :)